# Customizing existing Umbraco admin pages

Tags: umbraco7

Hi I am able to find information for creating your own custom section but have unsuccessful in finding anything on customizing the existing admin pages.

I essentially want to rename some of the field labels

Answer (score 1):

To rename the labels in the backoffice, take a look at the `/umbraco/config/lang` folder. There you can find all the different translations of the backoffice.

Just search on the label you want to edit and type in the new translation for the correct language.

After that you have to recycle the app pool in order to update the changes.